# Widget is not function in Android studio

Tags: flutter

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project/widget/widget.dart';

```
class ThreeWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  void onBabLogoPressed(BuildContext context) => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Widget()));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 232, 232, 232),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 331,
              height: 99,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 31, top: 326),
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => this.onBabLogoPressed(context),
                color: Colors.transparent,
                textColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                child: Text("",),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`Widget` is  not a function

Comment: Widget is an abstract class and can't be instantiated. Use ```Container()```.

Answer (score 0):

You're using

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Widget()))
```

which is incorrect since you can't instantiate widget like this. All you need to do is create a `Stateful/Stateless` widget and use it here, for instance you may create a new Widget like:

```
class MyNewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(...);
  }
}
```

And now you can use

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyNewWidget()))
```